# Why do I get the error: "Access is denied" when trying to print to a PDF?

Tags: c#

I developed a web application using iTextSharp. When I run the code with iTextSharp, users receive the following error message:

> Access is denied: "C:\inetpub\vhosts\bookmygroups.com\httpdocs"

Here is my code:

```
PdfWriter pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, 
    new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate you question please, it's currently too vague to answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

It's likely because the Asp.Net Hosting process does not have access to write to that particular directory.  You will need to grant the hosting process access to that directory in order for your web app to be able to write to it.

This CodeProject article goes into detail on how to appcomplish this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Ahmed_Kader.aspx